# MediaElement.js - Splash Screen for Audio Playback

Tags: audio, splash-screen, mediaelement.js

Is there a way to display a static splash screen to accompany an audio clip using MediaElement.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to change the source of an image file on the play event of MEJS. Look in the bottom right hand corner of the site for an example of how the JS is generally formatted: http://mediaelementjs.com/

For you, the event listener would look something like:

```
mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
 document.getElementById('myImgID').src = 'funnybunny.jpg';
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I basically ended up doing something like this. Manually creating and managing the splash screen with events.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, it's customary to flag it as such. If you have a better answer, please post it below for other stack overflow users in the future ;)